# How can Javascript code can be executed in order to get useragent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, googlebot

I have an email marketing website with user-tracking capability and this is normally what I do.
I ask to my customers to add this code to their websites in order to track behavior of their customers.

```
var _ssprt=('https:'==document.location.protocol?'https':'http');
var ig = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('googlebot') > 0;
document.write('<img height="1" width="1" src="'+_ssprt+'://www.myurl.com/system/sitecode.php?t='+document.title+'&adres='+document.location.href+'&ua='+ig+'" hspace="0" />');
```

Normally if one enters to the website through a browser, I can detect its user-agent easily.

However, if this is **GoogleBot** , since it executes the website as source code, it wouldn't send any datas to my main url. **It cannot execute the php as well.** 
Thus, I cannot see if any googlebots enter to the website.

I use this code in order to get the user-agent

```
var ig = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('googlebot') > 0;
```

I thought I can redirect my **sitecode.php** to js via htaccess. 
So it will behave as **sitecode.js** and I will include it with **script src code**

I am wondering if I had done this, googlebot would have executed that JS.

I am trying to do this with this piece of code but I couldn't succeed. Also, I am not sure if Google would execute this and send me the user-agent data.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sitecode.js$ sitecode.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: The problem is the website that people put my code is not mine. Think like Google Analytics. If there is a chance to do this with robots it would be great to get your suggestion.

Comment: you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] in php to check for "googlebot" ?

Comment: Again the problem is 'Googlebot Cannot execute PHP'

Comment: _“[The GoogleBot] cannot execute the php as well” – neither can or does any client browser. PHP is executed on the server – when a client makes a request that triggers the start of a PHP script.

Comment: The only way you can reliably track googlebot page requests is server-side from the server that is hosting the page in question.  You can't insert javascript in that page to track these types of accesses because the googlebot doesn't execute that script.

Comment: The problem is Google Analytics can detect the GoogleBot without executing the code as well as other Analytics services such as Yandex.  They don't require any server-side solutions.

Comment: @SNaRe — If Google Analytics can detect GoogleBot, why doesn't GoogleBot show up in my Google Analytics report?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer on this website which answers to my question.

http://searchengineland.com/is-googlebot-skewing-google-analytics-data-22313

Postscript: Google Analytics posted a response in the comments:

“The official Google bot does not execute Google Analytics JavaScript. We’re not sure what it is exactly, it could be anyone’s bot, some intern’s experiment, or other such traffic.”
I agree with this comment in that the official Googlebot reads JavaScript but does not execute it. Besides, it does not store and send cookies, which means that Paves/Visit would be exactly 1 and time on site exactly 0. Lastly, If the officiall Googlebot did execute JavaScript, we would have seen massive ammounts of visits.

It is also important to note that although we used Google Analytics as an example, we mean all JavaScript based solutions, including Omniture, Yahoo Web Analytics, WebTrends and others.

Please note that this issue requires additional investigation both in regards to Google Analytics and to how Google Search uses the Googlebot.

Answer (score 0):

My interpetation is that you **do** want to detect GoogleBot hits on your page? Or at least detect them so you can filter them out in your own code?

GoogleBot can interpet some JavaScript, but it does not execute it as a browser. And Google is quiet about what GoogleBot is doing when it comes to interpeting scripts. The same problem exists when the user has disabled JavaScript, then you will not see their visits.

There are ways to make [AJAX content crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) by GoogleBot, but it will also require some server code.

Unfortunatly, the safest way to make sure you track all visitors is to use server side code.

Optionally - and I suggest this with some reservation as I have not tried it myself - you could try adding an img or a hidden link to your php-page on your side and then check the user agent and referer to get the page that the user was visiting - but I'm not entirely sure it works that way and that GoogleBot will send the refered-header. Maybe someone else have tried this out?

Answer (score -1):

`navigator.userAgent` is available only in a browser environment. Googlebot just does a HTTP fetch, it *does not run* client side JavaScript. Its like fetching a page with wget or curl - you just download the page content (source/HTML) but not execute the scripts within.

To track googlebot accesses, you'll need to put in some server side solution, but depending on what server side technology your customers use, you'll need to provide snippets to support multiple server side technologies.

Comment: But how Google Analytics and other analytics services such as Yandex  do this without any server site solutions?

Comment: Google Analytics too won't send any data if you are fetching the page with curl or wget (give it a try: `wget http://yourpageurl`). It probably logs googlebot accesses (i'm not sure it does) because google itself is sending the bot requests and it knows when and to which pages etc.

Comment: I wrote 'yandex' on purpose to my previous comment since I thought someone would tell 'this is google. He will find a way to figure this out'. Yandex and any other analytics software can detect the GoogleBot without any server side solution

Comment: I've never seen any hosted analytics service detect any search engine indexing bot.